# Change textcolor of UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, background, textcolor

I am making an epub reader, into which I am loading HTML pages in my `webview`:

```
[_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_pagesPath]]];
```

Now I want to change background color and and text color of my the HTML pages. I changed background color of my webview using,

```
self._webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self._webview.opaque = NO;
```

That's working, but I also want to change the text color of my webview. How do I do this?

Comment: Is there any way to do programatically ? because on some pages i want text color as black and in some pages i want text color as white.

Comment: will have a problem if you color your text using css? did you mean you want to change the text color of ONE SINGLE .html black or white?

Comment: i want to change color of my html file programtically. there are lots of html pages, in some html pages i want text color as white and in some pages i want text color as black, tht's why i want to change text color.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this this code  `color:#fff` tag use for text color #fff use black color

```
NSString *webStr =@"Your text use";

[self._webview  loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div id ='foo' align='left' style='line-height:18px; float:left;width:300px; font-size:13px;font-family:helvetica;background-color:transparent; color:#fff;>%@<div>",webStr] baseURL:nil];
```

if you use **local html** the use

```
 NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"];

NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",htmlFile);

NSLog(@"Hello");

[self._webview  loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body bgcolor=\"#000000\" text=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Bookman Old Style, Book Antiqua, Garamond\" size=\"5\">%@</body></html>", text] baseURL: nil];
```

Comment: i am loading html file locally from my machine like this, `[_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_pagesPath]]];`

Comment: what is `changeColor` in your EDIT ? i have not added any class like `changeColor` in my css

Comment: are you use css or local html

Comment: ya, i am loading file from my local machine,`[_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_pagesPath]]];` where `_pagesPath` is `/Users/krunal/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/D414BC19-C005-4D93-896D-A6FB71DE4D21/Documents/first.html` here `first.html` contains text of black color, i want to change that text color as white.

Comment: @ketansahasrabudhe, please drag this.html in your project

Comment: i am getting `SIGABRT` here `[self._webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NS....
`

Comment: [self._webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                pathForResource:@"first" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

Comment: ya i wrote, `first` instead of test still `SIGABRT`i think error is in  nsbundle

Comment: dude you rock you helped me a lot it working now.. thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

```
[_webview loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body style=\"background-color: white; font-size: 17; font-family: HelveticaNeue; color: #ffffff\">%@</body></html>", strDataFromHTML] baseURL: nil];
```

Comment: dude i am reading a html file from my simulator path, like `/Users/krunal/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/D414BC19-C005-4D93-896D-A6FB71DE4D21/Documents/first.html` and i don't know, what will be the content inside `first.html`

Answer (score 1):

[I made a method](https://gist.github.com/rsaunders100/8711151) that wraps some text in a HTML body with the correct style for a given `UIColor` and `UIFont`.

Simply pop the generated HTML into the webview:

```
NSString * htmlString = [MyClass htmlFromBodyString:@"an <b>example</b>"
                                           textFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]
                                          textColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, stole your code and made a category from it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small Swift Extension to handle this:

```
import UIKit

extension String
{
    func htmlFormattedString(font:UIFont, color: UIColor) -> String
    {
        var numberOfColorComponents:Int = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor)
        var colorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor)

        var colorHexString = ""
        if numberOfColorComponents == 4 {
            var red = colorComponents[0] * 255
            var green = colorComponents[1] * 255
            var blue = colorComponents[2] * 255

            colorHexString = NSString(format:"%02X%02X%02X", Int(red), Int(green), Int(blue)) as String
        } else if numberOfColorComponents == 2 {
            var white = colorComponents[0] * 255

            colorHexString = NSString(format:"%02X%02X%02X", Int(white), Int(white), Int(white)) as String
        } else {
            return "Color format noch supported"
        }

        return NSString(format: "<html>\n <head>\n <style type=\"text/css\">\n body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@; color:#%@;}\n </style>\n </head>\n <body>%@</body>\n </html>", font.familyName, String(stringInterpolationSegment: font.pointSize), colorHexString, self) as String
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Can you tell me how can I load my string to web view after passing this extention

Answer (score 0):

try to add the code in your HTML file what ever you are getting from server...  then only you can change the text color.... or add some HTML code before your HTML file for changing the color of text

Answer (score -1):

try this...

1. Parse the html file .
2. Show the contents as per your requirements.

Hope this helps.