# iOS change font of content in UIWebView after full loading by javascript

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, fonts

I'm confusing with javascript on UIWebView.

The user can choose one from several fonts. Xcode says it change font successfully, but I don't see the changes. My code for "Courier New" shown below, for example:

```
NSLog(@"change font to Courier New");
NSString *result = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.fontFamily =\"Courier New\""];
    if (!result) {
        NSLog(@"fail");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"success: %@", result);
    }
```

Then the log is:

```
2012-07-20 16:01:24.122 javascript[1792:f803] change font to Courier New
2012-07-20 16:01:24.124 javascript[1792:f803] success: Courier New
```

but I don't see the font change in view.

How do I fix it?

Thanks?

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291689/change-textcolor-of-uiwebview/11291807#11291807 and use this tag

Comment: thank you, but not my problem. I want to change font after the web's content is loaded. It can be some fonts, then user choose the font he wants

Comment: Have you found any solutions ??

Answer (score 4):

Try this, works for me:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily =\"Courier New\""];
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, use this in `webViewDidFinishLoad`

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily =\"HelveticaNeue\"");
```